# Find out why php-fpm is consuming up to 100% CPU

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, php, nginx

I have my application installed on cloud hosting Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS, using PHP 5.5.9 and nginx 1.4.6 , and randomly i find out that my CPU is totally consumed by 1 job of `php-fpm: pool www`, but the memory has normal usage,

my `www.conf`:

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 3
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.status_path = /status
chdir = /
catch_workers_output = yes
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
```

I monitored the nginx access logs, it looks normal not flood attack detected,

How to know what is causing randomly the CPU consumption up to 100%?, and if i need to increase the CPU's cores?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7076784/3569208) hints about why mem usage is low.  About _"How to know what is causing randomly the CPU consumption up to 100%?"_ wait is up and check in that moment. (maybe `top -c` will be enough ...).

Comment: Nice hint for the memory usage issue, for the cpu usage, the output of htop or top -c is always one job php-fpm: pool www that consumes up to 90-100%, but i need to know what exactly is causing that, if it some kind or access or php script or mysql ....etc

Comment: Did you tried with [pstree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pstree) too? [Another reference](https://bobcares.com/blog/how-to-troubleshoot-high-load-in-linux-web-hosting-servers/#find-over-loaded-resource) for hints... and [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/201366/troubleshooting-php-high-cpu-on-production-server) for apache modules...

Comment: It could be as simple as a badly written PHP script.